# Kibana did not load properly. After setting up with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, nginx, proxy, kibana

I have setup the reverse proxy for the aws elastic search endpoint on a server on port 9200. I am trying to access kibana on that particular server with /kibana URI. But I am getting below error.

```
Kibana did not load properly. Check the server output for more information.
```

Nginx Code:

For ElasticSearch:

```
server {
    listen 9002;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         https://search.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com;
    }
}
```

For Kibana

```
location /kibana/ {
        proxy_set_header Host https://search-es.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP 34.214.177.249;
        proxy_pass https://search-es.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/;
        proxy_redirect https://search-es.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/_plugin/kibana/ http://ab.cd.ef.g/kibana/;
        }
```

For My App:

```
location / {
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3054;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                }
```

I am also getting a lot of below console error.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway).

http://ab.cd.ef.g//_plugin/kibana/ui/favicons/favicon.ico
```

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the Access Policy on your Elasticsearch Service Domain?

Comment: Try making the deploy at `https://search-es.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/kibana/` instead of `https://search-es.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/kibana/` it would make it easier for your to reverse proxy

Comment: @JamieStarke Only one particular IP of this server where we have setup nginx is allowed.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am not able to find any difference in your syntax.

Comment: I meant try removing `_plugin` from the url where kibana works now and then reverse proxy it

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am using Amazon ElasticSearch service. They have given the kibana URL. After removing /_plugin/ It is giving 404 because there is nothing on /kibana.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx reverse proxy setup for Kibana:

I am using Kibana 7.5 version I have faced this issue with Nginx. I have added configuration for following entries in the Nginx configuration file. It is fixed.

/app|/translations|/node_modules|/built_assets/|/bundles|/es_admin|/plugins|/api|/ui|/elasticsearch|/spaces/enter

Comment: Can you please share that config with us?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [server.basePath](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html) to `/kibana`

> Enables you to specify a path to mount Kibana at if you are running
>   behind a proxy. This only affects the URLs generated by Kibana, your
>   proxy is expected to remove the basePath value before forwarding
>   requests to Kibana. This setting cannot end in a slash (/).

Comment: I am using AWS ElasticSearch. Is it possible to change this configuration there?

Comment: It's a Kibana configuration, so it would go in your `kibana.yml`. If you use Elastic Cloud, Kibana is provided for you and you don't have to worry about hosting it yourself.

Comment: I am trying to route traffic to My Elastic Cloud from only one server IP. This server is under a VPC. As AWS doesn't have the provision to use Elastic Search under VPC, I am doing it through this method.

Comment: @MohitKumar, did you ever find a solution.  I have the same issue.